# asp net start angular app

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

Maybe this is answered before but I couldn't find it. If this is the case a good link will be great.

I'm developing an angular application in top of an ASP.NET app. I communicate them through a restful service. The problem is when I run from visual studio my app (using IIS) it goes to url

```
http://localhost:51061/
```

As I can't get into this page i get an error 403 forbidden. I want that when I push run inside visual studio my app start in.

```
http.//localhost:51061/AngularApp/
```

Global.asax.cs

```
   namespace WebApi {
        public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            protected void Application_Start()
            {           
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);    
            }
        } 
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
namespace WebApiPrC
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "backend/api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at ""Project > Properties > Web > Start Action" section?

You can specify however you want the app to start, e.g. "Current Page", "Specfic page" and "Start URL" etc. I guess you want to enter the url to "Start URL" box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. It was an easy fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Webapi is a framework for resource transmission between server and client (data only) and for views routing you have set up Angular routing .
In this case,angularApp application angular routing is useful like :

```
AngularApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
       when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'xxx.html',
    controller: 'xxxcontrollername'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login.html'
  });
```

}]);

Hope So its help you.

Comment: I have my angular routing in the angular application. My question is how to tell visual studio to run http://localhost:51061/AngularApp/ as default route